# Backup software to download MySQL (incremental) updates

Tags: backup

I am looking to find a Windows based software which remotely connects to a MySQL database server and downloads incremental updates (over FTP). I have seen a few like [Sitevault](http://www.site-vault.com/) and [HandyBackup](http://www.handybackup.net/) but am wondering if there are any more.

Some key requirements:

1. Must be able to download over FTP
2. Must be able to download from mysql
3. Must support incremental backups and versioning
4. Must be windows based software

Any price less than $500 is fine. This is not for a WordPress site.

Comment: What is missing in the two products you mention? This site is for recommending software, not for collecting lists of *what is available?*

Comment: The problem is that Sitevault does not work well with databases. And HandyBackup is very slow with FTP.

Comment: Now [edit] that into your question. Also: any price range? And BTW This is not a Wordpress site using MySQL I hope ;-), otherwise there are plenty of plugins.

Comment: I'm having the same quandry.  I have used both sitevault and handybackup.   Sitevault updates have stopped totally and its a shame as it was working ok for many of my domains.   Their support are not answering either.   

Handybackup I haven't had much luck with.  Seems slow and unreliable so far from testing.